# PHP header url location

Tags: php, session

I need help in figure it out how about to change the header location on my script below.

I need help in figure it out in changing the header location using a variable or user a mod_rewrite. I'm moving the application to another server hostname and there is about 300 pages with hard code header location url.

It will be easier to user the mod_rewrite. What will be option to do it.
Also can it be the header location use the php variables.
Thank you.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedNetID'])){
        $loggedNetID=$_SESSION['loggedNetID'];
}
else {

        header("Location: https://its0010.net/onestop/login.php");

}
$inactive = 600;

// check to see if $_SESSION["timeout"] is set
if (isset($_SESSION["timeout"])) {
    // calculate the session's "time to live"
    //reset time
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if ($sessionTTL > $inactive) {
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: https://its0010.net/onestop/login.php");
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['timeout']=time();
    }
}
?>
<!-- Session end -->
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a variable

Comment: there are many file, find and replace, tools

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Good  solution**

1. Extract part of code which is **the same in each page** in separate file, e.g. `top.php`
2. Walkthrough all files, remove unwanted code and `include` that file there.

Do it now and you will save a lot of time making similar changes.

---

**Bad solution**

Anyway, if you want quick and dirty solution, and you're using Linux, use `find` (in conjunction with `sed`) to search and replace in directory, e.g.

```
find /path/to/files -type f -exec sed -i 's/its0010.net/example.com/g' {} \;
```

The above command will replace all occurrences of `its0010.net` with `example.com`

Comment: vitozev, Thank you for you input. I will follow your advise.